# Css code for design and scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the color of the side bar. when I try to make the browser window small the color at the bottom left is like a faded black and white and I am trying to make the scrollbar hidden but still can scroll and also looking a CSS code that can make the word steady when I close and open my side navigation menu.

Thank you for helping me in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V57e1.png)

my css code

```
    .contentnav{
        height: 100%;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding-top: 50px;
        transition: left 0.3s linear;
        width: 50px;
        display: block;
   }

                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
                    background: #115a01;
                    outline: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
                }

                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                }

                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 0.4em;
                }

   .contentnav ul li ul{
        display: none;
   }

   .contentnav ul i{
      margin-left: 10px;
      color: #FFFFFF;   
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 25px;
      padding-bottom: 8px;

      cursor: pointer;
      vertical-align:middle;
   }

   .contentnav ul{
     list-style: none;
     margin:0px;
     padding:0px;
   }

   .contentnav ul span{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
   }

   .contentnav i:hover{
     color: rgba(0,204,102,1);  
   }
```

my html code

```
   <div class="contentnav" id="contentmenu">
   <ul>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Home</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">L</span>
            <ul>
                <li>-Bo</li>
                <li>-B</li>
                <li>-R</li>
                <li>-E</li>
                <li>-P</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-hourglass-half"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Online</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-bookmark"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">E</span>
            <ul>
                <li>-S</li>
                <li>-Fee</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">C</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">G</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Announcement</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Calendar</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fab fa-hire-a-helper"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Guides</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
            <span id="same" class="nav-text">Logout</span>
        </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick.

Remove this and

```css
                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
                    background: #115a01;
                    outline: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,1);
                }

                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
                    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
                }

                .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    width: 0.4em;
                }
```

Replace it with this.

```css
.contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-button
  {
    display: block; 
    height: 13px; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    background-color: #AAA;
  } 
.contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-button:hover
  {   
    background-color: #AAA; 
  } 
.contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
  { 
  background-color: #CCC; 
  } 
  .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
  { 
  background-color: #CCC; 
  } 
  .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-track
  { 
  background-color: #efefef; 
  } 
  .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar-track:hover
  { 
  background-color: #CCC;
  } 
  .contentnav::-webkit-scrollbar
  { 
  width: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sir but it still not working. i think i am gonna use a third party, a bootstrap template 'coz tired of doing my own navigation menu. haha :) glad someone help me.

Comment: @GenghisHalliwel No problem, although I do prefer using bootstrap since it makes my life so much easier. Gives you more time to perfect the back-end work.

Comment: but .... i think i can't. still eager to finish this haha. Maybe i can ask for a help with you to look my work @JamesBond?

Comment: @GenghisHalliwel to hide the scroll bar completely you can use `overflow: hidden;` or if you just want to hide the x or y axis you can use `overflow-x: hidden;` or `overflow-y: hidden;`